# Riesz potential of a set and its complement

Tags: integration, fractional-calculus, potential-theory

Let $F\subset [0,1]$ be a closed set, $G = [0,1]\setminus F$, $\alpha \in(1,2)$. Is there a simple condition on $F$ under which the integral
$$
\int_F\int_G \frac{dx\,dy}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}
$$
is finite?

I suspect that if the fractal dimension of $\partial F$ is small, then this is the case.

Comment: I'm not sure that the title is correct, so feel free to edit.